# Call VS Code Extensions from within Java or Python Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working with an old, faulty API that gives me wrongly formatted JSON files. I found an VS Code Extension that fixes the received file. Is it somehow possible to call that Extension from my file. It is possible to place it in either my Java or Python code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most extensions are open sourced. So in your case, dig the source code of that extension and replicate the same logic in your own Java or Python code.

Comment: Just port the extension to a Node.js app/script and use that as system command of you Java/Python application